# SharePoint Access Database, get users?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

Is there a simple (any) way to create a database within SharePoint (I'm editing it with MS Access) and have a linked table to SharePoint's user list?

I want to modify the builtin sample "Problem database" to not use its own User table but to use SharePoint's user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always link to the user table, and you can do so for any application you publish.

And you can do this even for non published (web) applications.

You may well have to delete the existing user table (so test/try on a copy).

To link, the first thing you need is the URL of the current published application. Assuming this is open in Access, then hit file, then you are presented with back stage and there are TWO places in which you can see the URL to the published site. Note how the one in green is a hyperlink that you can click on (I use that often to ensure I launch the correct web site in my browser).

[image]

However, we need to do a cut + paste, and thus note the URL in blue above. You can click on that URL, highlight it, and then right click and "COPY" the URL into your paste buffer.

Now from the main page, simply link to the table on the SharePoint site. From the External data tab, choose SharePoint list.

[image]

Now, paste in your URL (you could type, but hey that too much work!).

Now, when the list of tables shows up, you see this:

[image]

From the above choose the user info table.

This will "replace" your published table with that of the user table. This tip works for both web and non web based applications in Access.

Albert D. Kallal (Access MVP)

Edmonton, Alberta Canada