# Access Web App Link To SharePoint User List

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to build a 2013 Access web application that uses the SharePoint 2013 user list as a lookup.  The SharePoint user list doesn't show up when linking to the SharePoint sites lists through add table and it doesn't work to link to /_catalogs/users/.  This is relatively simple to do with SharePoint lists but I haven't been able to find any way to do it within an Access web application table.

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796437/sharepoint-access-database-get-users

Answer (score 1):

You cannot link a web Database to a SharePoint list.

This is because the data in a web database is actually kept as a special SQL Server database in Azure. It is an entirely separate infrastructure.

You will need to create two databases if you want to do everything in Access. One for the web data and one to pull everything together.